# How do I split an array into two-dimensional arrays? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create a two-dimensional array based on `targetItems` with the number of numbers in `splitNumber` and output it as follows.

```js
const targetItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const splitNumber = 2;
```

We are looking for the following results.

```js
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]];
```

Is there a good way?

I was thinking of using Math.round, etc. to carry it out if it can't be done evenly.
If the number of targetItems is 5 and the splitNumber is 2

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5]]
```

If the number of targetItems is 17 and the splitNumber is 2

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]]
```

If the number of targetItems is 5 and the splitNumber is 3

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [5]]
```

Comment: Does it have a consistent behavior when the number cannot be evenly divided? Like, if 100 is divided into 6, should the program give you `16,17,17,16,17,17`, or 
`17,17,17,17,16,16`  or `16,16,17,17,17,17` or use some other order?

Comment: I was thinking of using Math.round, etc. to carry it out if it can't be done evenly.
If the number of targetItems is 5 and the splitNumber is 2
[[1,2,3], [4,5]]
If the number of targetItems is 17 and the splitNumber is 2
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]]
If the number of targetItems is 5 and the splitNumber is 3
[[1,2], [3,4], [5]]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we use the `arary.slice(start,end)` method `splitNumber` of times, having the bigger parts first. The results depend indeed on how you define the problem in the first place. So this code might need changes.

```js
const targetItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function split(targetItems, splitNumber) {
  const half = Math.ceil(targetItems.length / splitNumber);

  var parts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < splitNumber; i++) {
    parts.push(targetItems.slice(i * half, i * half + half))
  }
  return parts;
}


for (var i = 1; i <= targetItems.length; i++) {
  console.log("split to " + i + " parts", JSON.stringify(split(targetItems, i)))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I get that you use `ceil`, but it's strange to see, in case of a 4 way split, 3,3,3,0 items. Would there be a way to do it that creates a more even split? Would `round` work?

Comment: Also, one of the other answers is literally a carbon copy of yours

Comment: I think you should use `floor` instead of `ceil`, that makes the splits a lot more even :)

oh no, never mind! That does not work at all. It would need to be more complex to make a more even split I guess.

Comment: (sorry for the spam haha) I guess a 'fair' divison there would be 3,2,3,2, when everything is properly rounded, but once again, the code will become more complex to achieve that

Comment: No it's ok. Specifically `floor` and `ceil` don't work here, but it's a challenge to make it like 3,2,3,2 for 10/4.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my previous project:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
const arr1l = Math.floor(arr.length/2)
  const arr2l = arr.length-arr1l
  const arr1 = arr.slice(0,arr1l)
  const arr2 = arr.slice(arr1l,arr.length)
var new_arr=[arr1,arr2]
document.querySelector(".h1").innerHTML=arr1
document.querySelector(".h2").innerHTML=arr2
```

```html
<p class="h1"></p>
<p class="h2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used in this way.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,1,2];

function turnIntoTwoDimension(arr) {
  let twoDimension = []
  
  twoDimension.push(arr.slice(0,arr.length/2))
  twoDimension.push(arr.slice(arr.length/2))
  
  return twoDimension
}
console.log(turnIntoTwoDimension(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const targetItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function split(targetItems, splitNumber) {
  const half = Math.ceil(targetItems.length / splitNumber);

  var parts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < splitNumber; i++) {
    parts.push(targetItems.slice(i * half, i * half + half))
  }
  return parts;
}


for (var i = 1; i <= targetItems.length; i++) {
  console.log("split to " + i + " parts", JSON.stringify(split(targetItems, i)))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```